# Makefile do not reevaluate variable with every call

Tags: makefile

It seems like Make does not persist the value of a variable but instead re-evaluates it every time you call it. For example:

I have a Makefile where I define a variable `MY_VAR` as the first twelve digits of a hashed version of the current date. I have three targets `target_1`, `target_2` and `target_3` that:

- `echo $(MY_VAR)` once
- `echo $(MY_VAR)` twice
- call `target_1` and `target_2`

When I run `make target_3`, I expect the same hash to be printed three times. But instead, I get something like:

```
>>> make target_3
017af0c6483b
9873732118e7
7c78d1e4ba89
```

Here the complete `Makefile`:

```
MY_VAR=$(shell date +%s%N | sha1sum | cut -c1-12)

target_1:
    @echo $(MY_VAR)

target_2:
    @echo $(MY_VAR)
    @echo $(MY_VAR)

target_3: target_1 target_2
```

What's the best way for persisting the value of a variable in Make, instead of re-evaluating? My current work around is that I write the first hash code into a file.